# What abilities/powers does each level of DOOMS give?

Tags: death-stranding

DOOMS allows a greater connection to the other side and to the Beach in *Death Stranding*. We see that Sam has a DOOMs level of 2 which means he can sense BTs but not see them. Fragile has a higher level meaning she can see BTs and she can teleport using the Beach. Higgs has an extremely high level of DOOMS and can even control BTs amongst other great powers.

**What abilities/powers does each level of DOOMS give?**